# Propper Syntax for Decorators which are instance methods

Tags: python-3.x

I was working on a project and was reworking part of the code base. In any case, I needed to make sure that a few function calls that modify the data structure only take place when we are sure that the data structure is valid. So my idea was to use decorators instead of painstakingly adding a guard clause to every function (although it only saves me a line - I thought it'd be a good opportunity to get to use decorators more).

Here's the simplified setup:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        # self.u = self.my_decorator(self.u)
        # self.v = self.my_decorator(self.v)
        # self.w = self.my_decorator(self.w)

    def my_decorator(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.a:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Attribute 'a' is False, cannot execute the function.")
        return wrapper

    # @my_decorator
    def u(self, arg1, arg2):
        print(f"Function 'u' called with args: {arg1}, {arg2}")

    # @my_decorator
    def v(self, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
        print(f"Function 'v' called with args: {arg1}, {arg2} and kwargs: {kwarg1}")

    # @my_decorator
    def w(self):
        print("Function 'w' called")

# Example usage
obj1 = MyClass(True)  # Set attribute 'a' to True
obj2 = MyClass(False)  # Set attribute 'a' to False

try:
    obj1.u(1, 2)  # This should work
    obj2.u(1, 2)  # This should raise a ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

try:
    obj1.v(1, 2, kwarg1="hello")  # This should work
    obj2.v(1, 2, kwarg1="hello")  # This should raise a ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

try:
    obj1.w()  # This should work
    obj2.w()  # This should raise a ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Uncommenting `self.u = self.my_decorator(self.u)` works and the function behaves as expected.
However, `@my_decorator` around the functions doesn't work. It produces the following error.

```
TypeError: my_decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

Fiddling around with ChatGPT, it suggested the following instead of the decorator as a member functions of MyClass, which works:

```
class MyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if instance.a:
                return self.func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Attribute 'a' is False, cannot execute the function.")
        return wrapper
```

Now I would *like* to get it to work without having to create a separate class for that. From a syntax perspective, I would think it has to work. I'm curious to understand how the inner workings of the python interpreter handle the wrappers that are child functions of a class and how it handles these quasi self-referential calls.

It would seem reasonable to prevent this from working since the class is not fully parsed by the interpreter at the time when the decorator is used. It would be possible to create two decorators which decorate each other and cause an infinite recursion while parsing the code, like this:

```
class Stupid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = self.dec_A(self.v)
        pass
    def v(self):
        print("v was called")
    # @dec_B
    def dec_A(self, fn):
        deced_fun = self.dec_B(fn)
        def new_func():
            return deced_fun()
        return new_func
    # @dec_A
    def dec_B(self, fn):
        deced_fun = self.dec_A(fn)
        def new_func():
            return deced_fun()
        return new_func
```

Which does in fact cause a RecursionError at Parsetime.

Anyhow - sorry for the rambly post - I hope some Master of Python can explain how and why this is not working as expected.

Or maybe the error is trivial and I'm just blind - who knows.

Thank you for your answers.

AliSot2000

Edit:
Changing the decorator to:

```
...
    @staticmethod
    def my_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.a:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Attribute 'a' is False, cannot execute the function.")

        return wrapper
...
```

also doesn't work. It raises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alisot2000/Documents/project/sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    class MyClass:
  File "/home/alisot2000/Documents/project/sample.py", line 22, in MyClass
    def u(self, arg1, arg2):
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your `my_decorator()` is basically being used as a staticmethod.  It *can't* be a normal instance method, because the class is not yet defined, so no instances of the class can even exist yet.  So decorate it as `@staticmethod` and get rid of the `self` parameter on the decorator itself, instead adding `self` to the `wrapper()` function.

Comment: Just define the decorator outside of the class if you *don't mean to use it as an instance method*. `staticmethod`s weren't made callable until recently (3.11 I believe)